# Retrieve PEM cert: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ssl, openssl, sslhandshakeexception

As many others I've got the error with Ruby: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed.

I downloaded a cacert.pem and tried to add it like this:

```
require 'net/http'

# create a path to the file "C:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem"
cacert_file = File.join(%w{c: RailsInstaller cacert.pem})

Net::HTTP.start("curl.haxx.se") do |http|
  resp = http.get("/ca/cacert.pem")
  if resp.code == "200"
    open(cacert_file, "wb") { |file| file.write(resp.body) }
    puts "\n\nA bundle of certificate authorities has been installed to"
    puts "C:\\RailsInstaller\\cacert.pem\n"
    puts "* Please set SSL_CERT_FILE in your current command prompt session with:"
    puts "     set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\\RailsInstaller\\cacert.pem"
    puts "* To make this a permanent setting, add it to Environment Variables"
    puts "  under Control Panel -> Advanced -> Environment Variables"
  else
    abort "\n\n>>>> A cacert.pem bundle could not be downloaded."
  end
end
```

And like this:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/https'

module Net
  class HTTP
    alias_method :original_use_ssl=, :use_ssl=

    def use_ssl=(flag)
      self.ca_file = Rails.root.join('lib/ca-bundle.crt')
      self.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
      self.original_use_ssl = flag
    end
  end
end
```

I even tried to cancel the check:

```
require 'faraday'
module Faraday
class Adapter
 class NetHttp < Faraday::Adapter
  def call(env)
    super

    is_ssl = env[:url].scheme == 'https'

    http = net_http_class(env).new(env[:url].host, env[:url].port || (is_ssl ? 443 : 80))
    if http.use_ssl = is_ssl
      ssl = env[:ssl]
      if ssl[:verify] == false
        http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
      else
        http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE # <= PATCH or HACK ssl[:verify]
      end
      http.cert    = ssl[:client_cert] if ssl[:client_cert]
      http.key     = ssl[:client_key]  if ssl[:client_key]
      http.ca_file = ssl[:ca_file]     if ssl[:ca_file]
    end
    req = env[:request]
    http.read_timeout = net.open_timeout = req[:timeout] if req[:timeout]
    http.open_timeout = req[:open_timeout]               if req[:open_timeout]

    full_path = full_path_for(env[:url].path, env[:url].query, env[:url].fragment)
    http_req  = Net::HTTPGenericRequest.new(
      env[:method].to_s.upcase,    # request method
      (env[:body] ? true : false), # is there data
      true,                        # does net/http love you, true or false?
      full_path,                   # request uri path
    env[:request_headers])       # request headers

    if env[:body].respond_to?(:read)
      http_req.body_stream = env[:body]
      env[:body] = nil
    end

    http_resp = http.request http_req, env[:body]

    resp_headers = {}
    http_resp.each_header do |key, value|
      resp_headers[key] = value
    end

    env.update \
      :status           => http_resp.code.to_i,
      :response_headers => resp_headers,
      :body             => http_resp.body

    @app.call env
  rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
    raise Error::ConnectionFailed.new(Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
  end

  def net_http_class(env)
    if proxy = env[:request][:proxy]
      Net::HTTP::Proxy(proxy[:uri].host, proxy[:uri].port, proxy[:user], proxy[:password])
    else
      Net::HTTP
    end
  end
 end
end
end
```

But no luck (and not the way you want to fix this). Weird thing is that it works sometimes.

Now I'm trying this, but have trouble finding the certificates:

```
require 'net/http'

url = URI.parse('https://www.xpiron.com/schedule')
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
sock = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, 443)
sock.use_ssl = true
store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
store.add_cert OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.new('addtrust_ca.pem'))
store.add_cert OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.new('utn.pem'))
store.add_cert OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.new('user_first_ca.pem'))
store.add_cert OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.new('xpiron.pem'))
sock.cert_store = store
sock.start do |http|
  response = http.request(req)
end
```

So I opened the `https://myserver.com/Request.ashx`request in chrome, clicked on the little lock-icon to get the certificate details. But I can't find any PEM files to export. I can see that it's a COMODO certificate. I don't own the server, so I got to find a solution for this on my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can disable certificate verification for a given instance of `Net::HTTP`:

```
stock.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

or you can disable SSL verification globally in your process using:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Note: Ruby interpreter will give you warning that constant is already initialized. Sometimes you might get hard error. if that's the case you can unassign constant and initialize it again using following code:

```
OpenSSL::SSL.send(:remove_const, :VERIFY_PEER)
OpenSSL::SSL.const_set(:VERIFY_PEER, OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
```

This is not a perfect solution for your problem, but if security is not a big cocern, you can use above methods to bypass SSL Cert verification. You will still have encrypted secure connection to server.

Comment: Where do I place the second one?

Comment: if you are using rails, then you add it to initializers. otherwise you can put it anywhere you want as long as you execute it once before starting to use `Net::HTTP`. after `require 'net/http'` in your script will work

Comment: `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` results with a syntax error: `dynamic constant assignment`

Comment: @bbozo you can always use first approach to disable for a given instance but not globally (second approach is more for dev mode where you are still experimenting with code and not production server). Either way, you can unset and set given constant to avoid dynamic const assignment. can you try following: `OpenSSL::SSL.send(:remove_const, :VERIFY_PEER); OpenSSL::SSL.const_set(:VERIFY_PEER, OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)`. make sure `net/http` is required